# Convert YAML string to JSON using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, yaml

I am able to convert a YAML file to JSON, but I am not able to convert a YAML string to JSON.  Is there any other way to convert YAML string to JSON?

**Sample Input**

```
---
:name:
  :firstname: Guru
  :lastname: Shyam
```

**Expected output**

```
{
  "name": {
    "firstname": "Guru",
    "lastname": "Shyam"
  }
}
```

Comment: "Any other way" than what? What have you tried? What's 'not working'? Are you receiving errors? If so, what are they? If not, how is your current output different than your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Pysch.load

```
data = "---\n:name:\n  :firstname: Guru\n  :lastname: Shyam\n"

Psych.load(data)
-> {
     :name => {
         :firstname => "Guru", 
         :lastname=> "Shyam"
        }
   }
```

Comment: I thought OP asked for a JSON output. This currently produces a Ruby hash, not a JSON string.

Comment: That is enough. We can easily convert the ruby hash to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`YAML.load_file` might help you.

Btw, it is an alias for `Psych` but has a more convenient name, and included in ruby standart library.

```
[2] pry(main)> .cat data.yml
---
:name:
  :firstname: Guru
  :lastname: Shyam
[3] pry(main)> require 'yaml'
=> true
[4] pry(main)> puts YAML.load_file('data.yml').to_json
{"name":{"firstname":"Guru","lastname":"Shyam"}}
=> nil
```